# Extract GPS coordinates from .docx file with python

Tags: python, regex, docx

I have some hectic task to do for which I need some help from python. Please see this word document.

[image]

I am to extract texts and GPS coordinates from each row. There are currently over 100 coordinates in 10 docx file. My "hefty" python knowledge get me to this.

```
from docx import Document
import re

main_file = Document("D:/DOCUMENTS/Google_Link/1  Category I/1  Category 
I.docx")
table = main_file.tables[1] #this is same for every document

data = []
keys = None

for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
   text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

if i == 0:
    keys = tuple(text)
    continue

row_data = tuple(text)
data.append(row_data)

regexReference = re.compile("(C.-)\w+")
colReference = [item[1] for item in data]

listReference = filter(regexReference.match, colReference)

for i in listReference:
    print i.encode('UTF-8')
```

I can print 16 reference ids from column 2. Please guide me to print something like this.

```
C1-20701-17-1

some site, some region

The existing CMC Office at Bariyodhala (22°40'34.3"N; 91°38'28.2"E) requires 
some repair/maintenance works including electrical wiring and electrical 
lights and appliances like ceiling fans supplies. Detail specification of 
the works are attached

x = 91°38'28.2"E
y = 22°40'34.3"N
```

These XY locations and descritions will be used to create KML files afterwards and attach  with each document. I'd prefer a variable for each part of the above section (ref id, location, description, x and y) so that I can automate that as well.

[demo docx](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=54877138522051155064&t=5487713852205115506459606)

Comment: I suggest you add a link to a demo docx file.

Comment: demo docx file link added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this works if there are files with different patterns (p.s. I'm using python 2.7.11):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from docx import Document
import sys
import os
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in files:
        doc_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        if doc_file.endswith('docx'):
            main_file = Document(doc_file)
            table = main_file.tables[1]  # this is same for every document

            data = []
            keys = None

            for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
                text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

                if i == 0:
                    keys = tuple(text)
                    continue

                row_data = tuple(text)
                data.append(row_data)

            regexReference = re.compile("(C.-[0-9-]+)")
            regexCoordinate = re.compile(r'(N-(.{,12})([0-9]|\')|[0-9].{,12}N)[;, ]+(E-(.{,12})([0-9]|\')|[0-9].{,12}E)')

            result = []
            for item in data:
                tmp = dict()
                matchReference = regexReference.search(item[1])
                matchCoordinate = regexCoordinate.search(unicode(item[2]))
                if matchReference:
                    tmp['reference'] = matchReference.group()
                if matchCoordinate:
                    tmp['x'] = matchCoordinate.group(1)
                    tmp['y'] = matchCoordinate.group(4)
                tmp['description'] = unicode(item[2])
                tmp['location'] = unicode(item[3])
                result.append(tmp)

            for rs in result:
                if 'reference' in rs:
                    for k, v in rs.iteritems():
                        print('{} = {}'.format(k, v))
                    print

# Output:
# --------------------------------
# y = 91°38'28.2"E
# x = 22°40'34.3"N
# description = The existing CMC Office at Bariyodhala (22°40'34.3"N; 91°38'28.2"E) requires some repair/maintenance works including electrical wiring and electrical lights and appliances like ceiling fans supplies. Detail specification of the works are attached.
# reference = C1-20701-17-1
# location = xxxxx Site, c Region
```

Comment: Thanks. This seem to almost work, except for the coordinate part. I am not using the `CURRENT_DIR`, because the files are not in same folder. The file names also do not have underscores. Please add an `os.walk` (for all files inside a folder) and remove the underscores.

Comment: Ok, I add `os.walk` and substitute filename by checking the .docx extension