# Need regex to extract characters from python dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary from where I could print out the `data['longitude']` and `data['latitude']` like this.

```
(91°38'28.2"E)(22°40'34.3"N)
(92°04´14.1´´E)(21°37´00.8´´N)
(E-092° 15. 715')(N-20° 56.062')
(91°49'10.63"E)(24°20'05.40"N)
(91°26'31.92"E)(24°07'35.15"N)
(90°08'15.07"E)(24°41'14.71"N)
(90°04'7.97"E)(24°42'29.34"N)
(90°04'10.06"E)(24°42'32.8"N)
(E-092° 15.776')(N-20° 56.065')
(91°46'26.90"E)(24°18'47.16"N)
(E-092° 15.649')(N-20° 56.023')
(91°46'26.90"E)(24°18'47.16"N)
(91°49'08.08"E)(24°20'06.33"N)
(92° 2'31.25"E)(21°20'58.79"N)
(E-092° 15.776')(N-20° 56.065')
(E-092° 15. 486')(N-20° 56.022')
```

I am to convert these number to decimal degrees. For example,

```
92° 2'31.25"E -> (92 + (2/60) + (31.25/3600)) -> 92.042
20° 56.023' -> 20 + (56.023/60) -> 20.993
```

Typical python character split couldn't work because the numbers have inconsistent patterns.

```
(data['longitude'][:3]) + (data['longitude'][5:2]/60) + (data['longitude'][8:5]/3600)
```

I used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536558/extract-gps-coordinates-from-docx-file-with-python) to extract these values from a docx file. Now I am stuck again.

Comment: what is your input, a list of tuples or a list of strings?

Comment: Have you tried playing around in an online regex tester? Like regex101.com?

Comment: Unicode or ascii?

Comment: My inputs are unicode strings - @RomanPerekhrest. I am still working with the regex code. `(N-(.{,12})([0-9]|\')|[0-9].{,12}N)[;, ]+(E-(.{,12})([0-9]|\')|[0-9].{,12}E)`. It needs to either search by 90-92 and 20-24 degree range first, or search the minute and seconds then come to degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Y7HXnQ/1/)):

```
import re

coordinates = """
(91°38'28.2"E)(22°40'34.3"N)
(92°04´14.1´´E)(21°37´00.8´´N)
(E-092° 15. 715')(N-20° 56.062')
(91°49'10.63"E)(24°20'05.40"N)
(91°26'31.92"E)(24°07'35.15"N)
(90°08'15.07"E)(24°41'14.71"N)
(90°04'7.97"E)(24°42'29.34"N)
(90°04'10.06"E)(24°42'32.8"N)
(E-092° 15.776')(N-20° 56.065')
(91°46'26.90"E)(24°18'47.16"N)
(E-092° 15.649')(N-20° 56.023')
(91°46'26.90"E)(24°18'47.16"N)
(91°49'08.08"E)(24°20'06.33"N)
(92° 2'31.25"E)(21°20'58.79"N)
(E-092° 15.776')(N-20° 56.065')
(E-092° 15. 486')(N-20° 56.022')
"""

rx = re.compile(r"(?P<degree>-?\d+)°\s*(?P<minute>[^'´]+)'")

def convert(match):
    try:
        degree = float(match.group('degree'))
        minute = float(match.group('degree'))
        result = degree + minute/60
    except:
        result = -1
    finally:
        return result

coordinates_new = [convert(match) for match in rx.finditer(coordinates)]
print(coordinates_new)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I ended up using this expression - `((?P<degree>\d+)°\s*(?P<minute>[^\'´]+)[\'´]?\b(?P<second>[^\"´´]+))`. I needed to convert the seconds too. I think you need to change `degree` to `minute` inside `minute = float(match.group('degree'))`.